# Axios post request with jsession id

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios, jsessionid

I need to log into Spring-build IP server remotely to be able to fetch images from it. I'm able to pass the form-data and to get the jsessionid from another call but I'm not able to log into the system.

I have express, axios, axiosCookieJar and tough in my app - the problem is, that even thought I'm able to get the cookie from the first call to IP server, I'm not able to pass it properly into the second call. I'm not able to log into the server and change it's authentication because it's legacy and it might do more bad than good - thus, I need to find a way to authenticate my session from NodeJS-client end.

```
const logIn = async (address, bodyFormData) => {
  const logIntoIP = await axios.request({
    url: `${ipLinkCompose(address)}`,
    method: "POST",
    mode: "cors",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      Cookie: cookieJar.getCookiesSync(addressip)
    },
    withCredentials: true,
    data: bodyFormData
  });
};
```

I'm able to do the same call using Postman - GET request to IP server to get the jsessionid and then second POST request with form-data that passeses the username/password.

As a result of my current call I get "Invalid username or password" - so the multipart/form-data works.

Comment: `"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",` is a **response** header, it has no place being on the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was - the server was using Digest authorization thus any tries failed. I was able to dig into the logs and found this in the application.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full cookie details from postman. This sounds like a similar problem i had. It worked on postman, but not on axios. I did something like this and it worked. Before i just had JSESSIONID. I added the rest of the info, which i got from the postman response, to the cookie field and it worked.

axios
.request({
    url: "http://url",
    method: "get",
    headers: {
        Cookie: "JSESSIONID=???; path=/???; domain=???; HttpOnly; Expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT;"
    }
})

Comment: The problem is - sometimes it does work, sometimes it doesn't (and I don't know why). And the whole bit is that it has to be automated from start to finish - so I'm unable to set the headers manually every time.